# IE 11 Missing Request Headers

Tags: ie11-developer-tools

On a GET XHR request, there are no Request Headers in the IE 11 console. The headers do exist in Chrome and Firefox.

How do I send headers with a GET request?

Answer (score 1):

When IE 11 caches a request there are no headers. I had to add a query param to the request (`?d=${Date.Now()}`) to ensure that the request was not being cached.

Comment: You can prevent caching on the API from the serverside, but the query param will probably catch nuances in IE that may not respect caching policies.

Comment: See this thread on other ways to fix the issue https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/777