# How to fix IE missing Header error (chorme & safari is ok. // Babel & Firebase used.)

Tags: internet-explorer, header

This is first time I write about my coding(?) problem....
I'm very new in front-end users...and my English skill is not good in now.

So, the problem as below.

the code was kinds of sending a data to server.
when I click the send a data below error code was showing now.

```
[object Object] data was what a want to send.
[object Object]{detail: "1234", email: "test@test", name: "test", phone: "010", title: "test", type: "n"}
[object Error]{description: "missing Header"(...", message: "missing Header"(...", name: "ReferenceEr...", number: -2146823279, stack: "ReferenceEr..."}
[object Error]{description: "missing Header"(...", message: "missing Header"(...", name: "ReferenceEr...", number: -2146823279, stack: "ReferenceEr..."}
```

Chrome and other modern browsers are working well.

the base story was as below.

I just made a  web page based on Firebase. But the client request compatibility for IE.

So, our Back-end programmer used Babel and some other things(I don't know exactly...)

It looks like many IE problems were almost fixed, but some errors still remain
But some errors still remained..

I know this question have too short for base information.

If someone let me know what kinds of information were need for problem solving, I will tell more information.

Comment: You can clear IE cache and try again. I find a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50456532/ie-11-missing-request-headers) and the issue lies on IE cache. You can try the solution in the answer to disable cache in IE. If the issue still exists, please provide [a minimal, complete, reproducible code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which we can run to test and reproduce the issue.